# Combine / merge multiple App into one

Tags: iphone, ipad

Im wondering, if I have ex. 10 apps. Is Its possible to combine all om Them into one app with a new screen ? (To iphone and iPad)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you need to merge the codebases and create a new main screen.